# about mybatis's parameterType for primitive data type?

Tags: mybatis

I use mybatis3.0.6 with java

Which one is better for performance?

1. `[select id="getData" parameterType="Integer" resultType="Integer"]`
2. `[select id="getData" parameterType="int" resultType="int"]`

I think "int" needs casting, am I right?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is no difference in using either.
eg-

```
 <select id="getById" parameterType="int" resultType="int">
    SELECT age FROM Person WHERE id= #{id}
 </select>

public Integer selectById(int id) {

    SqlSession session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession();

    try {
        Integer age =  (Integer) session.selectOne("Contact.getById", id);
        return age;
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

In this case the return from selectOne has to be cast to Integer for it returns an Object type, whether resultType is int or Integer.

Comment: There was `parameterClass` , was that in iBatis ?